# Redirect in parent controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, acl

in my ZF2 (2.4.5) project I have main (parent) controller with function to validate user rights so every inherited controller can easily acces it. However there's a problem with redirect. I know that inherited controller's action has to return response, but is it possible to force redirection in parent controller?

Parent controller

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class CoreController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function checkAccess($moduleName, $accessName){
        if($this->getAclService()->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName)){
            self::redirect()->toRoute('access-denied');
        }
    }
}
```

Inherited controller

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Application\CoreController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class InterfaceController extends CoreController{

    public function indexAction(){

        $this->checkAccess('Foo', 'Bar');

        return new ViewModel([

        ]);
    }
}
```

TL;DR If I call `$this->checkAccess('Foo', 'Bar');` in `InterfaceController` and `$this->getAclService()->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName)` in `CoreController` returns `false` I want to redirect user to route `'access-denied'` immediately without completing rest of `InterfaceController::indexAction`

Important: I want to avoid checking what `checkAccess` returns, I just force redirection.

Thanks in advance for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did this using global exception handler

Child controller

```
<?php

namespace Warehouse\Controller;

use Application\CoreController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends CoreController {

    public function getWarehouseDocumentAction() {
        parent::checkAccess('Warehouse', 'incoming-goods');

        return new ViewModel([
            'foo' => 'bar',
        ]);
    }

}
```

Parent controller

```
namespace Application;

use Application\Exception\InsufficientPermissionException;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class CoreController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function checkAccess($moduleName, $accessName){
        if(!$this->getServiceLocator()->get(MyAcl::class)->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName, $this->identity())){
            throw new InsufficientPermissionException('Access denied. Insufficient permission.');
        }
    }
}
```

Module.php

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Application\Exception\InsufficientPermissionException;
use Application\Monolog\Handler\DoctrineLogMessageHandler;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

        $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', 'dispatch.error', function (MvcEvent $event) {
            if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
                $exception = $event->getParam('exception');
                if ($exception instanceof InsufficientPermissionException) {
                    $target = $event->getTarget();
                    return $target->redirect()->toRoute('access-denied');
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Permissions are held in database.

Comment: Nice. The other option which I forgot about is to use the init() method in the parent controller. This is called before any child actions and can initiate the redirect. Just make sure to do the redirect before passing control back to the child classes.

Comment: Updated my answer with EDIT #2

Comment: Hmm, as I understood you check access right before action should start but is something like this does not fit me. My controllers are kinda big and I think it's my code design problem. For example I got one view with form, I want to grant access to user to see form but block access after form submit. I'm aware it's not like it should be but code id over 1 year old and team grown from 1 person, me to 6 people. Moreover we mostly create new features than refactoring code.

Comment: I see. Yes, that is different from our code base as we use ACLs to restrict at the URL level. We do detailed checks (workflow type checks) but that is at the action/view level for us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here by saying that is not possible. The calling code, InterfaceController::indexAction, needs to at least *return* which will start the redirect process.

You can clean it up a bit by letting the base controller set the redirect but the inherited controller needs to stop the script execution by calling *return*.

Base Controller

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class CoreController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function checkAccess($moduleName, $accessName){
        if (!$this->getAclService()->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName))) {
            self::redirect()->toRoute('access-denied');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Inherited controller

```
use Application\CoreController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class InterfaceController extends CoreController{

    public function indexAction(){

        if (!$this->checkAccess('Foo', 'Bar')) {
            return;
        }

        return new ViewModel([

        ]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As a side note, in our company we do our ACL checks in the base controller's init() method with is not overridden and therefore can do the redirect instantly before any *action* code is run.

**EDIT #2**

I totally forgot about the init method which we use. Give this a go if you're looking for another solution.

Base controller

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class CoreController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function init() {
        // bootstrap code...

        // This should redirect
        if (!$this->_isUserAuthorized()) {
            return;
        }

        // If the ACL check was OK then pass control to controllers
        return parent::init();
    }

    private function _isUserAuthorized() {
        // checks done here
        // return true if OK
        // else

       $this->_response->setRedirect($this->view->defaultUrl($redirect))->sendResponse();
       return false;
    }
}
```

Inherited controller

```
use Application\CoreController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class InterfaceController extends CoreController{

    public function indexAction(){

        // nothing to do here

        return new ViewModel([]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i want to avoid. Maybe EventManager would help?
@edit i need multiple checking in single action.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a simple 302 http redirect to "access-denied", so you could just render the response object thus far and stop php execution:

```
public function checkAccess($moduleName, $accessName){
    if (!$this->getAclService()->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName))) {
        self::redirect()->toRoute('access-denied');
        $this->getResponse()->send();
        exit;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**or** you could simple throw an exception:

```
public function checkAccess($moduleName, $accessName){
    if (!$this->getAclService()->isAllowed($moduleName, $accessName))) {
        self::redirect()->toRoute('access-denied');
        throw new \Exception('access denied');
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the exception will prevent further code execution and the redirect will prevent the exception error page to be rendered.